# Typescript: Setting variable type dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 variables:

```
let locals 
let visitants
```

Each of them can be of type `PlayerDto` or `TeamDto`. Type will depend on third variable called `competitor_type`. If `competitor_type` is `player` then I would need to assign a list of Players to `locals` and `visitants`, other ways a list of teams.

I am solving it using "any"

```
locals: any
teams: any
```

Is there a better way of solving it?

Comment: is `competitor_type` another variable?

Comment: yes, it is another variable

Comment: You cannot base a Type on the value of a variable.

Comment: You can do this: `let locals: PlayerDto | TeamDto` then have an if statement to check if the value is of a specific type `if(locals instanceof PlayerDto) {} else if(locals instanceof TeamDto){}`

Comment: That was what I was looking for!!!, thanks, please add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not base a type on a variable, however you can list the types that a variable can be by using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (`|`) to list all the different types like this:

```
let locals: PlayerDto | TeamDto
let visitants: PlayerDto | TeamDto
```

Then when using this it is offten needed that you check the type by using an `instanceof`

```
if(locals instanceof PlayerDto) {
  // Do something for PlayerDto
}
else if(locals instanceof TeamDto) {
  // Do something for TeamDto
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap the different versions in an Object, to then be able to narrow down the types:

```
let state: {
  type: "player";
  locals: PlayerDto[] | undefined;
   visitants: PlayerDto[] | undefined;
} | {
  type: "team";
  locals: TeamDto[] | undefined;
  visitants: TeamDto[] | undefined;
} = { type: "player" };
```

Then your code is always typesafe:

```
 if(state.type === "player") {
   state.locals // is of type PlayerDto[]
 }

 state.locals // is of type PlayerDto[] | TeamDto[]
```

To change the type, do:

```
 state = { type: "team" };
```

then you can reassign `state.locals` and `state.visitants`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use union type.

```
let locals: PlayerDto[] | TeamDto[];
```

Doing this you are saying that `locals` can be either list of PlayerDto or list of TeamDto.

More details on union and other advanced types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html